# Treatment effect measured by Likert scale

Tags: correlation, treatment-effect, ab-test

I'm analysing data from a study with a control and a treatment group.
There are four questions on purchasing decisions for different products. Each question uses a 4-point Likert scale asking respondents about their attitude towards some products. For Example:

*Control Group*:

|  | Strongly Disagree | Disagree | Agree | Strongly Agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I would purchase A.1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| I would purchase A.2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| I would purchase B.1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 2 |
| I would purchase B.2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

*Treatment Group*

|  | Strongly Disagree | Disagree | Agree | Strongly Agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I would purchase A.1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| I would purchase A.2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| I would purchase B.1 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| I would purchase B.2 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 |

I want to understand if treatment significantly influences the purchasing decision for one of the two product groups (A or B).

What is a suitable test for this?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple response variables to a binary treatment variable. Not confident enough to give as an answer, but consider a mixed effects model for the effect of AB treatment on likert response with product being a random effect. Or do t-tests for each question yielding lots of p-values with low statistical power... Or a generalized linear model predicting each question response with the A/B treatment (perhaps in a seemingly unrelated regression if errors are correlated). These are just flailing suggestions.

Comment: You probably want to use ordinal regression. This will allow you to test the effect of Treatment across all the data while accounting for *Group*, and *.1* or *.2* if those are meaningful. ... If you had a larger sample size, you might just do multiple Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney tests, each for *A.1*, *A.2*, *B.1*, and *B.2*.

Comment: Thank you. My example might be misleading. The actual sample size is larger, around 200 total (100 per group).

Comment: Still, ordinal regression is probably the best approach.  But if you want something simple, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney tests will suffice.  (In that case, you can just code your SD, D, N, A, SA responses as e.g. 1,2,3,4,5.).  Question: do you have multiple responses for the same person ?  That is *Respondent 1* answered about both *A* and *B* ?  If so, did you record the data in way where you know the answer *Respondent 1* gave to each of *A* and *B* ?

Comment: Thank you @SalMangiafico! I was a bit late here. I do have four responses per person for all persons and I have a unique participant ID per participant. Does this change the approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Answer from my comments:***

You probably want to use ordinal regression. This will allow you to test the effect of *Treatment* across all the data while still accounting for the effect of *Group*,  as well as *.1* or *.2* if those are meaningful.

But if you want something more simple, you might just do multiple Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney tests, each for *A.1*, *A.2*, *B.1*, and *B.2.*. (In that case, you can just code your SD, D, N, A, SA responses as e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

The appropriateness of either of these approaches may change depending on the answer to this question: Do you have multiple responses for the same person ? That is *Respondent 1* answered about both *A* and *B* ? If so, did you record the data in way where you know the answer *Respondent 1* gave to each of *A* and *B* ?